# F# compile FSharpChart: inline error

Tags: f#, fsharpchart, f#-charting

I tried to compile FSharpChart libary from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/04/01/fsharpchart-wrapping-the-system-windows-forms-datavisualization-charting-charting-types.aspx, and got compile error like

```
Error   1   The value 'StackedArea100' was marked inline but its implementation makes use of an internal or private function which is not sufficiently accessible
```

from

```
type FSharpChart =
    /// Displays multiple seriesÿof data as stacked areas. The cumulative proportion
    /// of each stacked element is always 100% of the Y
    /// axis.
    static member StackedArea100<'TY when 'TY :> IConvertible>(data: seq<'TY>) = 
        GenericChart<_>.Create<StackedArea100Chart>(oneY data)
    /// Displays multiple seriesÿof data as stacked areas. The cumulative proportion
    /// of each stacked element is always 100% of the Y
    /// axis.
    static member inline StackedArea100<'TX, 'TY when 'TX :> IConvertible and 'TY :> IConvertible>(data:seq<'TX * ('TY)>) = 
        GenericChart<_>.Create<StackedArea100Chart>(oneXYSeq data)
    /// Displays multiple seriesÿof data as stacked areas. The cumulative proportion
    /// of each stacked element is always 100% of the Y
    /// axis.
```

Can anyone enlighten me what's going on? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why the `StackedArea100` (and other similar members) should be `inline`. You can fix it by replacing all occurrences of `static member inline` with just `static member`. If you can post a comment to the F# team's blog post, that would be great (so that they can correct this in the next release).

*To add some more details:*

The reason why the F# compiler doesn't like the code is that the `oneXYSeq` function that is used in the implementation should be `internal` and so the `StackedArea100` cannot be inlined (because it would need to access an inaccessible helper function). The reason why it works in F# Interactive is that the `FSharpChart.fsx` file is loaded into the current assembly, so `internal` members are visible.

Andy why is there unnecessary `inline` in the source code? It is because I originally experimented with using hat-types e.g. `^T` to write generic members that work with any numeric type (and hat types require `inline`). Then we decided to switch to `IConvertible`, so the `inline` annotation is no longer needed.